# iPhone wallet not giving back device ID and Push token

Tags: ios, push-notification, applepay, wallet, passkit

I ran into a problem while integration "Registering a Device to Receive Push Notifications for a Pass" web service on my server for Apple Passes.
Link Below: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html.

I've followed the following steps:

1. Able to successfully generate and distribute Apple Pass on iPhones through a downloadable link.
2. Once pass is downloaded, I'm adding that pass to Apple Wallet. While adding, Registration web service is called which must send my server a Device ID and Push Token, but I am getting these two parameters as nil.
3. However when I'm hitting the same URL on AdvanceRestClient(with dummy Device ID and Token), I do get the callback.

I wanted to know why I'm not getting device Id and Push token from iPhone??

Comment: Can you post your webServiceURL or an example of the url that you believe should work?

Comment: "https://example.com/v1/devices/devicelibraryIdentifierFromiOSDevices/registrations/pass.com.company.storecardtest/959555599"

Comment: this is a post request with Content-Type as application/json and authorization key as header

Comment: is there any setting that i need to enable in iPhone to get device ID and Push token?

Comment: Ok, so your link is correct and nothing extra is required to get the phone to register.  Try hooking the phone up to a mac and read the console logs as you toggle automatic updates on and off.  You should be able to see the device making calls to the url.

Comment: Connected my iPhone to Xcode debugger. Error:
`passd(Security)[144] <Notice>: could not enable test hierarchy: ApplePinningAllowTestCertsApplePassbook not true`
`message 'kCLConnectionMessageRegistration' received from client 'com.apple.Passbook'`
`getClientEffectiveRegistrationResult, /Applications/Passbook.app/Passbook, com.apple.Passbook, , CLClientRegistrationResult, kCLClientRegistrationResultFailedUnavailable, CLCommonLocationServicesEnabled, 1`
`could not enable test hierarchy: ApplePinningAllowTestCertsApplePassbook not true`
`The connection to ACDAccountStore was invalidated`

Comment: `PassbookUIService(UIKit)[353] <Error>: if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction`


`PassbookUIService(UIKit)[353] <Error>: if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction`

Comment: I was connected to mobile data when this error occurred. But strangely, once I connect to WiFi everything started working fine (I get push token and device ID). I faced this issue twice in two different iPhone 6.

Comment: Is this issue to do something with mobile data?

Comment: Is your webService hosted locally on the same network?  Do you have firewalls that prevent external traffic from accessing your network externally?

Comment: Mobile data and WiFi both are in open network without any proxy. Web service is in a proxy but is accessible from outside as call is working fine with open mobile data and WiFi from other iPhones except iPhone 6.

Comment: This is not a proxy issue, as the same is replicated even when my server and iPhone are kept in open network.